# Wrapping panels in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following layout in my window:

1. `Grid` with two columns
2. `GridSplitter` which resizes grid columns
3. Second grid column is filled with `StackPanel`
4. `StackPanel` is oriented vertically and has 2 children: `TextBlock` and a `WrapPanel`
5. `WrapPanel` has two `Grid`s as children
6. First `Grid` child contains one `Image`
7. Second `Grid` contains a StackPanel with 3 `TextBlock`s oriented vertically.

The XAML code looks like this:

```
<Window>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
      <TextBlock Text="Now here's a silly poem for you." />
      <WrapPanel>
        <Grid Name="GridForImage">
          <Image Width="200" Height="200" Source="Image.jpg" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Name="GridForText">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="Roses are red." />
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="Violets are blue." />
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="You belong in a zoo." />
          </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
      </WrapPanel>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Once the window opens, the second column is wide enough to allow grids `GridForImage` and `GirdForText` to be placed next to each other horizontally. If I shrink the width of the second column using the grid splitter, the `GridForText` grid gets placed underneath the `GridForImage` at one point, which is quite expected.

Here's what I would like to achieve:

1. I want `GridForText` to shrink its width to a certain size and to remain positioned to the right of the `GridForImage`, as I move the grid splitter to the right side of the window. Then, when the width shrinks to a certain value, say 200px, it should get placed underneath the `GridForImage`, i.e. `WrapPanel` should do its magic. Right now, the `GridForText` doesn't resize at all, it just gets placed underneath when it's current width becomes too large for the width of the `WrapPanel`.
2. When the `GridForText` does get placed underneath the `GridForImage`, I want `GridForImage` to fill the entire width of the `WrapPanel`'s width.

Is all this possible and what should I do? Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially trying to use two distinct layout modes so you just need to set up the two distinct states in your layout and then add bindings or triggers to switch between them at the point when you want to switch modes (i.e. width = 200). Using a Grid is the most flexible and gives you a lot more control over the relative sizes but requires more settings and would work best in a ControlTemplate or DataTemplate where you can use Triggers to set a bunch of things at once based on a condition.

Here's a more compact example using UniformGrid with some Bindings and a converter. I removed the fixed sizing on the Image - try Stretch="Fill" if you care more about filling width than aspect ratio. I also changed one StackPanel to a DockPanel to maintain vertical stretching for its children and added a Background to one of the TextBlocks just to show how much Width it's really getting:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <DockPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock Text="Now here's a silly poem for you." DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={x:Static local:LayoutModeConverter.Row}, ConverterParameter=200}"
                     Columns="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={x:Static local:LayoutModeConverter.Column}, ConverterParameter=200}">
            <Image Source="Image.jpg" />

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="Roses are red." Background="Red" />
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="Violets are blue." />
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="You belong in a zoo." />
            </StackPanel>
        </UniformGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

And the converter:

```
public class LayoutModeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public static readonly LayoutModeConverter Row = new LayoutModeConverter { RowMode = true };
    public static readonly LayoutModeConverter Column = new LayoutModeConverter { RowMode = false };

    public bool RowMode { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double width = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
        double targetWidth = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);
        if (RowMode)
            return width > targetWidth ? 1 : 2;
        else
            return width > targetWidth ? 2 : 1;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a question: Since your solution involves `UniformGrid`, that means that when the content is displayed in two rows, both of them will share the same height. I would prefer if both rows would take only the height necessary to accommodate their content. Is that possible? I tried replacing the `UniformGrid` with `Grid` and playing with `Grid.Row`, `Grid.Column` and `Grid.ColumnSpan` but it doesn't work as I have expected. Could you give me some advice? Thanks.

Comment: Try changing the VerticalAlignment of the content objects. Stretch is the default but any of the other settings will only use as much space as they need instead of all that is given to them by their container.

Comment: That won't work. The nature of the `UniformGrid` is to make each of its cells equal. The content of the first cell is an image with the height 200px and the content of the second cell are the 3 text blocks - i.e. since the image height is greater that the height of the 3 text blocks, the height of all cells in the uniform grid will be dictated by the image height. The problem is the usage of the uniform grid and that cannot be overcome with vertical alignment. :(

Comment: You should try it. The size of the cells is just the amount of space available to the content contained in them. The space actually used by any given element is determined by the combination of the available space and the Width/Height, Alignment, and Margin settings on the contained element.